# Laravel - Request does not contain my inputs

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have the following form :

```
<div class="container text-center search-container">
    <form id="search-form" action="" method="post">
        <div class="nopadding col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
            <select name="huge" class="form-control input-block-level selectpicker search-selector" data-style="btn-default btn-fill btn-block">
                <option disabled>Search in...</option>
                <option value="1" selected>foo1</option>
                <option value="2">foo2</option>
                <option value="3">foo3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="nopadding col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-block-level search-bar" id="searchbar">
        </div>
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="nopadding col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-fill search-button input-block-level" type="submit">Search</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I use  `bootstrap-select` for the `select` element.

This calls a method in my controller, however when I do a `dd($request->all()`, here is what I do obtain :

```
array:2 [▼
  "huge" => "1"
  "_token" => "somethingReallyLongAndBoring"
]
```

Basically, I am not able to retrieve my inputs. Any idea what I did wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add `name` attribute to the input field.

`<input type="text" class="form-control input-block-level search-bar" id="searchbar" name="searchbar">`